# Sending UDP Packet to NTP to get a packet back (in ruby)

Tags: ruby, udp, ntp

What I need to do: 
Send a packet to pool.ntp.org (and I am assuming I get a packet back automatically).

The following just does not work for me. I have no solid idea of what I am doing, so for now I would be satisfied if I could reach the address and get the packet back. The code below just hangs. Any and all help would be appreciated.

```
require 'socket'
sock = UDPSocket.new
sock.connect("pool.ntp.org", 123)
sock.recvfrom(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation on UDPSocket](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html#method-i-connect) states:

```
connect(host, port) 
Connects udpsocket to host:port.

This makes possible to send without destination address.
```

That means that you may use `send(mesg, flags)` form of the `send`, nothing more. You need to send a request message to the NTP server to get a reply

You can see the NTPv4 protocol specification here: [RFC 5905](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5905.txt)

Comment: Does that mean I need to use bind(host, port)? "sock.bind("pool.ntp.org", 123)" gives me "Cannot assign requested address" error. I need to bind a socket to that address so that I can send/recieve from here?

Comment: No, `bind()` is for binding socket to the local port/interface so the packets you will be sending are originated from specific interface and/or port. So you may use `connect()` as you initially did, but you need to `send()` a request first in order to `receive()` any reply